# Is there a practical limit to the weight I can put on top of my kitchen cabinets?

Tags: kitchens, cabinets, load

How do I get a sense of what kind of load my kitchen cabinets will hold?

The building is 12 years old, as is the kitchen fitout (we did not do the fitout ourselves so I don’t have the plans and don’t know how much it cost.) We’re in Germany, if that gives you any hints as to construction techniques or materials.

The cabinets themselves are laminated 18mm MDF; 330mm deep and each unit is 600mm wide. The wall the cabinets are hung from is reinforced concrete. I’m not exactly sure how they’re attached, but I include a picture of one of the attachment points with the blanking plate removed.

Top edge of kitchen cabinets with bottles sitting on it:
[image: top edge of kitchen cabinets with bottles sitting on it]

Hardware that attaches a kitchen cabinet to the wall:
[image: hardware that attaches a kitchen cabinet to the wall]

Obviously failure of either the MDF or the attachment points would be catastrophic but my contention is that I’d have to hang my whole weight off the top of the cabinets and swing around a bit to make that happen. Even then it would be the MDF snapping rather than the thing pulling out from the wall.

Are there standards up to which these kinds of things must be built in Germany? If not, can anyone give me a heuristic for calculating how much (static) load they should be able to bear?

Comment: Even poorly made/attached cabinets hold a surprising amount of weight. Ask 10 of your friends if they have *ever* heard stories of upper cabinets falling down. My suspicion is that the result will be zero.

Comment: It could be unsafe because it may be difficult to get to a bottle without knocking other ones off accidentally.

Comment: I do have to be careful of that @AndrewMorton, but we’re in an apartment and there’s really no other place to store them so it’s a risk I have to take.

Comment: @RobertAtkins I can imagine little chrome safety rails around the top of the cupboard, but a quick search didn't give me any useful results. Maybe you could make some from wood? Or "spice rack for cupboard door" could give you the extra storage location you want.

Comment: There are no standards, material and installation factors vary widely, and we'd all be speculating. Voting to close.

Comment: Are you sure there are no standards, @isherwood? https://www.beuth.de/de/norm/din-68881-1/783996 (I’m not 100% sure it’s got load ratings in it because I haven’t ponied up the €25 yet.)

Comment: Well, in many years of home construction I've never encountered talk of such standards, nor have I witnessed inspectors concerning themselves with cabinet capacity. So, no, I'm not sure, but I'm fairly confident. Of course, things could be different over there. If I'm wrong I'm wrong.

Comment: If your experience isn’t in Germany it may not be relevant. They’re big on that sort of thing over here.

Comment: True, but then that applies to almost everything we discuss here. Also, standards do not in any way guarantee performance.

Comment: And this is why I’m annoyed by your vote-to-close. What you’re effectively saying is “nobody can know anything, anyone’s kitchen cabinets might collapse at any time” and if that’s the case what in the hell are we doing here at all? “Here is the standard, the work is new enough to be covered by the standard and done according to the standard so you’re probably fine” is a totally reasonable answer and quite possibly correct in this case!

Answer (score 4):

The best you can probably do is a proof test. It's just not possible to decide the controlling limit state without significant disassembly. What's the anchor embedment in the concrete, for instance?

To conduct a proof test, decide the capacity that you want (obviously this must be a reasonable value), multiply it by 1.2, 1.25, 1.5, or some other reasonable safety factor. Now apply this load to the cabinets to test them. The strength is probably a function of eccentricity from the wall, so apply the load at a reasonable offset from the back of the cabinets. I would do something like 75% of the cabinet thickness measured from the back.

Note that the US's wood design code has a "load duration factor" of 1.6 for 10 minute load durations (like gusting from major wind loads or from earthquakes). For 10 year load durations, it's 1.0. This implies that wood (sawn lumber, not MDF) has a short load-duration strength of 1.6/1.0 = 1.6 of its long load-duration strength. A proof test has a short load-duration. You should therefore divide your proof test's established capacity by 1.6 to get a long load-duration capacity, where I assume the long load-duration capacity is more appropriate for your cabinets.

The cabinets are probably connected to each other, so it might be a good idea to uncouple one of them from the others, test only the one, and then assume that its established capacity applies to the other cabinets as well.

If the controlling limit state is something like the bolt tearing out of the wall, then a proof test failure won't damage the cabinet. That's only if you construct something to prevent the cabinet from falling, however, so you might do something to catch the cabinet in case it falls.

Comment: So you’re suggesting fill/stack it with plate weights? It has been full of bottles for over two years so far and it’s been fine. Is that enough evidence that it will continue to be fine?

Comment: As they say in the financial world, past performance is not an indication of future performance. To put it in blue-collar terms, it will continue to work great until it doesn't.

Comment: @RobertAtkins, I revised the load duration adjustment from 1.25 to 1.6. Whoops. Think of wood's strength as following an exponential decay curve. Just because your cabinets hold up the load today, doesn't mean that there's sufficient strength to hold up the load for 2 years or 10 years.